# Tailwind css from not found in production

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, aws-amplify

For hosting a next js app, I am using AWS Amplify. While building the project this error occurs.
[image]

Basically, this error is for not finding `tailwindcss/form`. In my local machine, it works totally fine.

`tailwind.config.js` looks like this:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "primary-violate": "#917AEB",
      },
      fontFamily: {
        poppins: ["Poppins", "sans-serif"],
        MaterialIcons: ["Material Symbols Outlined"],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/forms")],
};
```

Can anyone help me in this regard? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

Did you install the Tailwind Forms plugin?

I sense you need to run `npm install -D @tailwindcss/forms` in your project so it can be included in the project's package.json.

Also, in any case this is an environment issue, try running `npm build` or `yarn build` on your local machine to see if you can replicate the error locally and have more context to the stack trace.

More on the plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tailwindcss/forms

Comment: Yes, I have installed the plugin and in package.json file, it is under the devDependency. I have also build in my local machine which works perfectly.

Comment: Now I'm not so sure what could be wrong here. Do you want to double check that your AWS server has your latest commit (which includes the updated package.json)?

If it helps, maybe delete the node_modules on the server and re-deploy.